# redirect with google_oauth2 on validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth

I got a validation on my model to allow only some emails to log in with GoogleOauth but for some reasons, it does not redirect me to the root path

I got my admin Model :

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :registerable, :rememberable, :recoverable, :timeoutable,
    :trackable, :validatable

  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]                     
  validates :email, :test_email



  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    admin = Admin.find_or_initialize_by(email: auth.info.email)
    admin.password = Devise.friendly_token.first(12)
    admin.skip_confirmation!
    admin.save!
    admin
  end

  private 

  def test_email
    errors.add(:email, message: 'Email is not correct') unless email.match?(/\A[a-z.\-]+(\+\d+)?@test\.fr?\z/)
  end
end
```

And my `OmniauthCallbacksController` :

```
  def google_oauth2
      @admin = Admin.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
      
      if @admin.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = 'success'
        sign_in_and_redirect @admin
      else
        session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra')
        flash[:error] = @admin.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
        redirect_to root_path
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: maybe try to pass the `:event => :authentication` to the sign_in_and_redirect method to force all authentication callbacks to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validates` expects a `boolean` return. Just adding an error is not enough.

Try this:

```rb
def test_email
  return true unless email.match?(/\A[a-z.\-]+(\+\d+)?@test\.fr?\z/)
  
  errors.add(:email, message: 'Email is not correct')
  false 
end
```